# header source file needed after compilation?

Tags: c

If I make `headerfile.h` and then `headerfile.c` with the source code for the functions. Once I compile the main C file `sampleprogram.c`

```
cc -o sampleprogram headerfile.c sampleprogram.c
```

Is that source file for the header still needed? 
Is `headerfile.c` and `sampleprogram.c` compiled and linked together?
Do you need to include the `headerfile.h` along with `sampleprogram` if you were to put the program on a usb drive and put it on a different computer?

Answer (score 5):

Headers are not required to execute a program or to use a shared/static library. However, headers are required to write code that uses the interface of a library. Usually, under RedHat distros, you'd have rpms that install the library (`libuv`) and rpms that install the headers (`libuv-devel`).

Therefore, without headers, you can execute a program, or you can link against a library. However, if you want to write code that uses the API of a library, you need the headers on your system.

If you compile a program and put it on a USB drive, all you need is the executable. However, you might need to recompile your program as the compiler targeted the specific architecture of the system it ran on. If you move the executable to another computer, it might not work.

Comment: C source files are not required to execute a program either, of course. Nor are they needed for users of a library.

Comment: "Headers are not required to ... use a shared/static library"

As a beginner, I'm just curious what use does a library have if you cannot use its API? Are you essentially just saying that linking won't fail without the header files, but the library will be useless? Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer:

No, it is not needed.

## Longer answer:

No it is not needed, because when you use `#include`, the content of the header file will basically be pasted in to the C file. Because of that, the executable will not need the header file nor the c file to run (they are compiled into the executable already by the compiler)

Comment: C source files are not required to execute a program either, of course.